# What's the essential script code of a SP Master_Page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I need to know what is the essential SP Master_Page code, extremely necessary to get the the master page alive! Working!
When you open any MP in SP, you see that there's many parts of code  unnecessary. 
Has anyone any documentation about this?

Answer (score 1):

Use minimal.master that is provided with SharePoint.

This will include only the bare minimum to run SharePoint out of the box.